# Access violation reading location on dynamic allocated matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matrix, access-violation, dynamic-allocation

I have a problem with a dynamically allocated matrix. I get this error: "Exception thrown at 0x009087AC in Tema 1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFDFDFDFD." What I'm trying to do is delete a line from a matrix:

```
void deleteLine(int **matrix, int &nrLin, int nrCol, int lineDel)
{
    for (int indexLin = lineDel; indexLin < nrLin; indexLin++)
        for (int indexCol = 0; indexCol < nrCol; indexCol++)
            matrix[indexLin][indexCol] = matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];
    nrLin--;
}
int main()
{
    int **matrix, nrLines, nrColumns, lineDel;
    ifstream file("datePB4.txt");
    file >> nrLines>> nrColumns;
    matrix= new int *[nrLines];
    for (int index = 0; index < nrLines; index++)
        matrix[index] = new int[nrColumns];
    for (int indexLin = 0; indexLin < nrLines; indexLin++)
        for (int indexCol = 0; indexCol < nrColumns; indexCol++)
            file >> matrix[indexLin][indexCol];
    cin >> lineDel;
    deleteLine(matrix, nrLines, nrColumns, lineDel);
    for (int index = 0; index < nrLines; index++)
        delete matrix[index];
    delete matrix;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error in the 5th line ("*matrix[indexLin][indexCol] = matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];*").

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think when the last iteration `matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];` indexLin is `n - 1 ` then you use `n - 1 + ` which is UB. Reading outbound of the array.

Comment: `indexLin + 1` will be out of range on the last iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: You must `delete []` when you have used `new []`, or the program is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo do you mean mixing `new[]` and `delete` causes UB? Your comment reads as if every program that leaks an array has UB...

Comment: 0xFDFDFDFD : Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark "no man's land" guard bytes before and after allocated heap memory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, passing a pointer you did not receive from `new []` (unless it's the null pointer) to `delete[]` is undefined, as is passing a pointer you did not get from `new` to `delete` (unless it's the null pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading outbound of the array:

```
matrix[indexLin][indexCol] = matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];
```

So the last iteration indexLin is equal to `nrLin -1` which is OK but in `matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];` you read `matrix[indexLin(-1 + 1)]` which is not an elelement of the array which causes the program carsh.

You can modify it to:

```
for (int indexLin = lineDel; indexLin < nrLin - 1; indexLin++) // here solves the problem in order not to read matrix[indexLen]
    for (int indexCol = 0; indexCol < nrCol; indexCol++)
        matrix[indexLin][indexCol] = matrix[indexLin + 1][indexCol];
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! Can't believe I didn't notice it

Comment: @RobertSperchez: Happy for that it works for you. In a real program an error of such sort is easily caught through using `Exception Handling`.